# Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=1, ELEMENT=1} in android

Tags: android, automation, appium

Displaying the error as:
`Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=1, ELEMENT=1}`

while executing the code:

```
DesiredCapabilities c=new DesiredCapabilities();
c.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
c.setCapability("deviceName", "871cd2f2");
c.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
c.setCapability("platformversion", "4.3");
c.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60");
c.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.vending");
c.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
URL U=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");      
WebDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(U,c);        
//AppiumDriver d=new AndroidDriver(U,c);        
Thread.sleep(10000);        
MobileElement m=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@content-desc='Search']"));
m.click();      
m.sendKeys("edthesis");
```

Appium console Error:

> [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.10.0 [Appium] Appium REST http interface
>   listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723 [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
>   [HTTP]
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","browserName":"","deviceName":"871cd2f2","newCommandTimeout":"60","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"4.3"},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","browserName":"","deviceName":"871cd2f2","newCommandTimeout":"60","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"4.3"},"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"","platformName":"android"}]}}
>   [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args:
>   [{"appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","browserName":"","deviceName":"871cd2f2","newCommandTimeout":"60","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"4.3"},null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","browserName":"","deviceName":"871cd2f2","newCommandTimeout":"60","platformName":"Android","platformversion":"4.3"},"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"","platformName":"android"}]}]
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1552640850731
>   (14:37:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [Appium] Could not parse W3C
>   capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank [Appium] Trying to fix W3C
>   capabilities by merging them with JSONWP caps [BaseDriver] The
>   capabilities
>   ["appActivity","appPackage","deviceName","newCommandTimeout","platformversion"]
>   are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
>   [BaseDriver] Number capability passed in as string. Functionality may
>   be compromised. [Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v4.8.0) session
>   [Appium] Capabilities: [Appium]appActivity:
>   com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity [Appium] appPackage:
>   com.android.vending [Appium] deviceName: 871cd2f2 [Appium]
>   newCommandTimeout: 60 [Appium] platformversion: 4.3 [Appium]
>   browserName:  [Appium] platformName: android [BaseDriver] W3C
>   capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app... and MJSONWP desired
>   capabilities {"appActivity":"com.google.... were provided [BaseDriver]
>   Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app...
>   [BaseDriver] Number capability passed in as string. Functionality may
>   be compromised. [BaseDriver] Capability 'newCommandTimeout' changed
>   from string ('60') to integer (60). This may cause unexpected behavior
>   [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not
>   recognized by appium: platformversion. [BaseDriver] Session created
>   with session id: dd472778-35d6-45db-9ccf-57328cb2aa3f [AndroidDriver]
>   Java version is: 1.8.0_151 [ADB] Checking whether adb is present [ADB]
>   The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK
>   root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with
>   SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb. [ADB] Using adb from
>   D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe [ADB]  [AndroidDriver] Retrieving device
>   list [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device [ADB] Getting
>   connected devices... [ADB] 1 device(s) connected [AndroidDriver] Using
>   device: 871cd2f2 [ADB] Setting device id to 871cd2f2 [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell getprop
>   ro.build.version.sdk' [ADB] Current device property
>   'ro.build.version.sdk': 18 [ADB] Device API level: 18 [AndroidDriver]
>   App file was not listed, instead we're going to run
>   com.android.vending directly on the device [AndroidDriver] Checking
>   whether package is present on the device [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell pm list
>   packages com.android.vending' [AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
>   [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2
>   wait-for-device' [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   871cd2f2 shell echo ping' [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to
>   device... [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell dumpsys
>   package io.appium.settings' [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is installed
>   [ADB] Getting package info for 'io.appium.settings' [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell dumpsys package
>   io.appium.settings' [ADB] Checking whether aapt is present [ADB] The
>   ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root
>   directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK
>   23+. Checking along PATH for aapt. [ADB] Using aapt from
>   D:\Appium\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe [ADB]  [ADB] The version
>   name of the installed 'io.appium.settings' is greater or equal to the
>   application version name ('2.11.0' >= '2.11.0') [ADB] There is no need
>   to install/upgrade
>   'C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
>   [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell
>   ps' [ADB] Device API level: 18 [AndroidDriver] Granting
>   android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE, CHANGE_CONFIGURATION,
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION by pm grant [ADB] Granting permissions
>   ["android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE","android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION","android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"]
>   to 'io.appium.settings' [ADB] Got the following command chunks to
>   execute:
>   [["pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE",";","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION",";","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",";"]]
>   [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell
>   pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE \;
>   pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION \;
>   pm grant io.appium.settings android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
>   \;' [ADB] Device API level: 18 [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell am start -W -n
>   io.appium.settings/.Settings -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c
>   android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' [ADB] Device API
>   level: 18 [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   871cd2f2 shell settings put secure mock_location 1' [Logcat] Starting
>   logcat capture [ADB] Getting device platform version [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell getprop
>   ro.build.version.release' [ADB] Current device property
>   'ro.build.version.release': 4.3 [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell wm size' [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell getprop
>   ro.product.model' [ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.model':
>   SAMSUNG-SGH-I747 [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   871cd2f2 shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer' [ADB] Current device
>   property 'ro.product.manufacturer': samsung [AndroidDriver] No app
>   sent in, not parsing package/activity [AndroidDriver] No app
>   capability. Assuming it is already on the device [ADB] Getting install
>   status for com.android.vending [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell dumpsys package
>   com.android.vending' [ADB] 'com.android.vending' is installed [ADB]
>   Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell am
>   force-stop com.android.vending' [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell pm clear
>   com.android.vending' [AndroidDriver] Performed fast reset on the
>   installed 'com.android.vending' application (stop and clear)
>   [AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect [ADB] Forwarding
>   system: 4724 to device: 4724 [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 forward tcp:4724
>   tcp:4724' [UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator [UiAutomator] Moving to
>   state 'starting' [UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar [UiAutomator]
>   Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar' [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 push
>   C:\Users\preethi.g\AppData\Local\appium-desktop\app-1.10.0\resources\app\node_modules\appium-android-driver\bootstrap\bin\AppiumBootstrap.jar
>   /data/local/tmp/' [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
>   [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell ps' [ADB] No
>   'uiautomator' process has been found [UiAutomator] Starting
>   UIAutomator [ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args:
>   ["-P",5037,"-s","871cd2f2","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","com.android.vending","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
>   [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online' [AndroidBootstrap] Android
>   bootstrap socket is now connected [ADB] Running
>   'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 871cd2f2 shell dumpsys window'
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] json loading complete.
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
>   [AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing [ADB] Device
>   API level: 18 [ADB] Running 'D:\Appium\Sdk\tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
>   871cd2f2 shell am start -W -n
>   com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity
>   -S' [Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session dd472778-35d6-45db-9ccf-57328cb2aa3f added to master session list
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1552640881307
>   (14:38:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) [W3C (dd472778)] Cached the
>   protocol value 'W3C' for the new session
>   dd472778-35d6-45db-9ccf-57328cb2aa3f [W3C (dd472778)] Responding to
>   client with driver.createSession() result:
>   {"capabilities":{"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"browserName":"","platformName":"android","appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","deviceName":"871cd2f2","newCommandTimeout":60,"platformversion":"4.3"},"browserName":"","platformName":"android","appActivity":"com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","deviceName":"871cd2f2","newCommandTimeout":60,"platformversion":"4.3","deviceUDID":"871cd2f2","platformVersion":"4.3","deviceScreenSize":"720x1280","deviceModel":"SAMSUNG-SGH-I747","deviceManufacturer":"samsung"}}
>   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 30591 ms - 855 [HTTP]  [HTTP] -->
>   POST /wd/hub/session/dd472778-35d6-45db-9ccf-57328cb2aa3f/element
>   [HTTP] {"value":"//*[@content-desc='Search']","using":"xpath"} [W3C
>   (dd472778)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args:
>   ["xpath","//*[@content-desc='Search']","dd472778-35d6-45db-9ccf-57328cb2aa3f"]
>   [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id,
>   class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator [BaseDriver]
>   Waiting up to 0 ms for condition [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to
>   android:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[@content-desc='Search']","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client:
>   {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[@content-desc='Search']","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding
>   '//*[@content-desc='Search']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: ''
>   multiple: false [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using:
>   UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.ImageView, INSTANCE=6]
>   [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result:
>   {"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"status":0} [AndroidBootstrap] Received
>   command result from bootstrap [W3C (dd472778)] Responding to client
>   with driver.findElement() result:
>   {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"1","ELEMENT":"1"} [HTTP] <--
>   POST /wd/hub/session/dd472778-35d6-45db-9ccf-57328cb2aa3f/element 200
>   1977 ms - 67 [HTTP]

Comment: you don't need to use **BROWSER_NAME** capability if you are testing the android app. Remove it and try to run the code.

Comment: Tried still displaying the same error

Comment: try **AppiumDriver** instead of **WebDriver**. Can you add the appium server log?

Comment: Tried with AppiumDriver displaying the same error and updated the appium console log please check

Comment: It looks like the connection is successful, but the cryptic returned message in the log makes me think it found more than one match.  Trying using either findElements (plural) into a List or add additional specs to your xpath to isolate which one of the multiple elements you want by including some other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the relevant code from the Appium Inspector session itself. You can execute your actions on the connected device and record them to generate correct code for finding the relevant element.

I have tried below on Android with my application. Hope might help you

```
DesiredCapabilities c=new DesiredCapabilities();
c.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
c.setCapability("deviceName", "871cd2f2");
c.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
c.setCapability("platformversion", "4.3");

// Android version is 4.3, try with heigher version emulator as well

c.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
c.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "60");
c.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.vending");
c.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
URL U=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");  

AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(U,c); 

Thread.sleep(10000);  

MobileElement m = driver.findElementByXpath("//*[@content desc='Search']"));
m.click();      
m.sendKeys("edthesis");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Androiddriver instead of appium driver AndroidDriver driver=new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

If not working then try by updating java client jar

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please epxlain how this works and why it is supposed to help. Do so by [edit]ing your post please.

Answer (score 0):

Update your java client to 6.0.0-BETA3 in maven dependency POM.XML file. It worked for me as 6.0.0-BETA3 comes with W3C compliance

`<dependency><groupId>io.appium</groupId><artifactId>java-client</artifactId<version>6.0.0-BETA3</version></dependency>`

Please find the details here: https://github.com/appium/java-client